# How to stop c++ console from outputting "tick"

Tags: c++

I haven't been able to find anything else about this online at all. I have a simple authenticator program, with a .dll injector written into it. If the key matches the one in the database, it will run the injector, and constantly check to make sure that the key is still active. For some reason, my console window outputs "tick" about every second. When the injector is taken out, and it is just the authenticator it will not do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>




#include "include/c0gnito.h"



std::string Key;
std::string hwid = GetHardwareID(); //Gets the hwid


char* StringToChar(std::string string) //A function to convert a string to a char
{
    return _strdup(string.c_str());
}

template <class T>
void msg(T msg) 
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}

bool FileExists(const std::string& fileName)
{
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(fileName.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}

void WriteStringToIni(std::string string, std::string file, std::string app, std::string key)
{
    WritePrivateProfileStringA(app.c_str(), key.c_str(), string.c_str(), file.c_str());
}

std::string ReadStringFromIni(std::string file, std::string app, std::string key)
{
    char buf[100];
    GetPrivateProfileStringA(app.c_str(), key.c_str(), "NULL", buf, 100, file.c_str());
    return (std::string)buf;
}

LONG address = 0x0;
BYTE newvalue[] = { 0x0 };
HWND hwnd;
HANDLE phandle;
DWORD pid;

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

const char* dllPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\sysproc.dll";
const char* procName = "Project1.exe";
DWORD procId = 0;

int main() //Entry point
{
    system("color b"); //Sets the color to blue

    Initialize("B2wVksYPzgCBOtNq8SFQ05GCuKrzwNIRytotMczYWCSv59sypLJhPEnLY9w8cmml"); //Connects to the authentication server

    if (FileExists("./Config.ini")) 
    {
        Key = ReadStringFromIni("./Config.ini", "License", "Key"); //Gets the key saved in the file 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Welcome, please enter your license key: ";
        std::cin >> Key; //Gets the user's key
        if (Authenticate(StringToChar(Key), (StringToChar(hwid)))) {}// Authenticates key & hwid
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid Key!" << std::endl; 
            exit(2000);
        }
        WriteStringToIni(Key, "./Config.ini", "License", "Key"); //Creates a file that stores the key entered
    }

    if (Authenticate(StringToChar(Key), (StringToChar(hwid)))) // Authenticates key & hwid
    {
        std::cout << "Sucessfully Authenticated!" << std::endl; 
        Sleep(2000);
        while (!procId)
        {
            procId = GetProcId(procName);
            Sleep(30);
        }

        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, procId);

        if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            void* loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

            WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);

            HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, loc, 0, 0);

            if (hThread)
            {
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
        }

        if (hProc)
        {
            CloseHandle(hProc);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }


    system("cls"); 
    std::cout << "Hardware ID: " << hwid << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "_______________________________________________________" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;

    std::thread auth([&]() //Authentication Thread that keep on checking the connection and user previleges
        {
            while (true)
            {
                std::cout << "Auth is checking..." << std::endl;
                if (!Authenticate(StringToChar(Key), (StringToChar(hwid)))) 
                {
                    exit(0);
                }
                std::cout << "Sucessfully Authenticated!" << std::endl;
                Sleep(60000); 
            }
        });

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any `"tick"`. The block of headers at top are standard C++ headers or Windows headers. I'm quite sure there is nothing which causes that strange `"tick"`. Finally... What is `#include "include/c0gnito.h"`? A header-only lib? A header for an extra lib? What would Sherlock Holmes tell you now? ;-)

Comment: c0gnito.h is the authentication website I use. Probably not the best, but it fills my needs for now. It is something with the injector, as I said above when that code is taken out it does not print "tick".

Comment: _c0gnito.h is the authentication website I use._ Sorry? To me it looks like a header. A header which declares or even defines functions. One of these functions obviously prints "tick". Do a full-text search for `"tick"` in the sources of whatever `c0gnito.h` represents, remove the output from that source, recompile, and you're done. (Somehow I miss your problem.)

Comment: Searched the entire solution for that already, no results found. And yes, c0gnito is a header for an extra lib.

Comment: If `c0gnito.h` is the API for a web service, it can also be that it receives the `tick` (as a kind of ping) from the resp. server and reflects the received message on console. In this case, I would look for console output. One option to catch that in the debugger: Select something in console. This will block `std::cout`. If you then pause the process in debugger you can have a look into stack from where it did come from.

Comment: So, if you don't want "tick" on the console, remove the injector or change it so it doesn't output "tick". What's the problem?